# Handle WebRTC ICE candidates (from TURN Server) manually

Tags: webrtc, stun, turn

I am working on WebRTC framework, establishing peer connection between two Android mobile devices for voice and video calls. And now I want to move my solution to the public network where the NAT plays a major role.

My solution has to work in Symmetric NAT as well, but my STUN server is failing to establish voice/video call when it the devices are connected in Symmetric NAT. So I went to TURN server setup and did the setup successfully by the help of the following tutorial.

[Free open source implementation of TURN and STUN Server](https://code.google.com/p/rfc5766-turn-server/)

[Setting up a TURN Server for WebRTC Use](http://www.dialogic.com/den/developer_forums/f/71/t/10238.aspx)

And I have successfully added this server into the ICEServers of my Android application and started getting `relay` ICE candidates.

The candidates I am getting looks something like this

```
a=candidate:2312680776 1 udp 33562367 115.113.119.170 52972 typ relay raddr 223.227.91.151 rport 25323 generation 0

a=candidate:2312680776 2 udp 33562366 115.113.119.170 64698 typ relay raddr 223.227.91.151 rport 25324 generation 0
```

Now my question starts:

How should I assume these candidates ?? (As I want to handle these candidates manually instead of just passing these candidates to the other end)

I know how to understand `srflx` but not `relay`.

relay is followed by my global IP address and port. So does that mean I have to listen on `raddr` and `rport` to catch the audio/video data??

How should I parse these candidates and get the audio/video data ??

**Note** : In wireshark I am able to see the data packets coming from my TURN server on the port which is not equal to both the `rport` fields mentioned above in candidates.

And I read somewhere that I have to listen for some Allocate Response from TURN server.

I really need to know how do I do that. Any help about this topic will be greatly appreciated.  :(

Comment: Why you need to do something with these candidates? Why you want to handle it manually?

Comment: Thanks for replying.. I am integrating my own audio/video exchange mechanism. So i need to know the other party's ip address and port and i am giving it to my engine so that my engine will take care of the voice/video calls. That is my requirement. And my solution is working with STUN. But not working under Symmetric NAT. That is my problem.

Comment: With TURN you won't operate with opponent's ip and port, but you will operate with TURN server address and port. TURN allocates relay for you and all your traffics go through this relay's ip and port

Comment: Yes. I agree with you. But what i wanted to know is based on the above ice candidates "ip address 115.113.119.170 and port 52972" is allocated for me by TURN server and if other party sends audio/video data to this ip and port i am going to receive it on the port "25323" right ??

When i am not under NAT this is true. But when i am under Symmetric NAT, i am not receiving any data on this port rather i am receiving some data on some unknown port. Is this expected ??

Comment: @Igor Khomenko: Waiting for your response.. Please continue the discussion. I would really like to know how i need to treat those parameters of the ICE candidate i received from TURN server.

Comment: As I understand, these address were allocated for you by TURN: 223.227.91.151:25323 and 223.227.91.151:25324 and your opponent will send data to these IPs and ports.